# Export Selected records from multiple feature classes to one feature class in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: export, arcgis-pro

I have used a select by polygon tool to select features in an area of interest from multiple feature classes.

How do I export the selection into one feature class in ArcGIS Pro?

At the minute the only way I can see is to export the feature from each layer seperately and then combine. I hope to do this in one command.

Comment: If your feature classes are road centerlines and parcels how would you combine them into one feature class?  I think you should provide more details about the feature classes that you are hoping to combine the selections from.

Comment: If they are all the same type (for example polygons) select them and execute Merge tool. Only selected features will be merged

Answer (score 1):

If all your FeatureLayers (with their individual selections) are the same geometry type then you could Append them all to an **existing** FeatureClass. As all tools honor selections feeding those layers into the Append tool will mean only the selections are copied into the target FeatureClass.

If the input layers have different fields (but are all the same geometry type) then you need to change the `schema_type` parameter. Suggest you read the help file for the Append tool as this single tool can do it all in one go for you.